# Get query data without foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Currently I make my query like this:

```
<?php
 function Data() {  
 $db = DB::getInstance(); 
 $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
 $results = $query->results();
 return ($results);
 }
 $listdata = Data();
?>
```

And when I want to see my information I have something like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <h1>Title</h1>
 <hr>
 <div class="row">
  ....
  ...
  ..
  .
  <?php foreach ($listdata as $v1) { ?> 
   <p><?=$v1->username?></p>
  <?php } ?>

 </div>
</div>
```

But if I want to put information see for example in the footer of the page I have to open a new `foreach`

As I can transform this code to open the query to the top of the page and simply llabar variables where I want without opening another `foreach`?

**Even better would defeat the function, I just want to put the query and data wherever.**

Thank you!

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking here. If there's more than one row being returned from the result then there needs to be *some* kind of iteration/loop to go over all the results. Otherwise, if you only want a single row then why not just select that single row in your query and only return that?

Comment: You should provide example input and your desired output.

Comment: I just need a single row, but I want to eliminate the function because I do not need. Try putting the WHERE does not work anything tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `echo $listdata[0]->column_name`   thou this will print only the first row......so to be precise  use a where clause in your sql statment

Edit: It will print only the first index in the array that contains the Fetched Data